# Cassandra datastax ipv6 connection

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When I try to connect to the Cassandra instance on a machine with an ipv6 address, I get this error.

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /2600:xxxx:2500:yyyy:zzzz:qwq:1143:6a0d:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/2600:xxxx:2500:yyyy:zzzz:qwq:1143:6a0d:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1483)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:280)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.connect(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:100)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    ... 159 more
```

I give endpoints like that:
cassandra_contactpoints: [2600:xxxx:2500:yyyy:zzzz:qwq:1143:6a0d]

```java
@Bean
public Cluster cluster() {
    return Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoints(getContactPoints())
        .withPort(getPort())
        .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
        .withQueryOptions(getQueryOptions())
        .withPoolingOptions(getPoolingOptions())
        .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build()))
        .withCredentials(environment.getProperty("cassandra.username"), environment.getProperty("cassandra.password"))
        .build();
}
```

Does the datastax driver support ipv6? My driver version is `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.1.4`

*I changed IP address in the logs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided what version of Cassandra® you're using in your question so we will make some guesses here.

Also, `3.1.4` version was first released back in Feb 14, 2017 which is already over 6.5+ years old and does not contain the support for IPv6 which was introduced in https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2226 beginning `4.0.1` version. `3.x` version was on maintenance support only for many years.

Refer to [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver/tree/4.x/upgrade_guide) to upgrade to the latest 4.x series.

Also, note that **DataStax** has graciously donated the Cassandra Java Driver to the ASF C* community (via [CEP-8](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA/CEP-8%3A+Datastax+Drivers+Donation) on Nov 7, 2023) and you could leverage the latest beginning the `4.18.0` [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver).

Maven Coordinates are below with [latest as of this writing as `4.18.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/java-driver-core):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

- [Releases](https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver/tags)
- Issues can be logged [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA) going forward
- Mailing lists are [`user@`](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@cassandra.apache.org) and [`dev@`](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@cassandra.apache.org)