# Cassandra java-driver Java 17 Compatibility

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

DataStax Java Driver 4.17 added Beta support for Java 17 per the [Upgrade Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/upgrade_guide/) docs.

This [Apache Thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dhov01s8dvvh3882oxhkmmfv4tqdd68o) from November 2023 makes it look like Java Driver is now part of the Apache Software Foundation.

I would like to update an application to Java 17 that uses the java-driver. My problem is I am unable to find details on Java 17 compatibility/support beyond the Beta announcement.

Is there a release document, spec or other documentation detailing planned or current compatibility for Cassandra java-driver and LTS Java versions including Java 17+?

Searched official DataStax docs: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/upgrade_guide/

Searched github https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver

Answer (score 1):

As [*JAVA-3042* mentioned](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-3042), this is only adding *testing* support for Java 17. And, [yes, the Java Driver is donated to ASF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77714321/10410162).

I can already see work in progress towards supporting Java 17 with the java driver [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-3078).

Answer (score 1):

As @Madhavan mentioned JAVA-3042 was completed for release 4.17.0 of the Java driver.  With this change we now test new releases of the Java driver against Java17 before release, so we can say that all versions from that point forward pass our test suite.  We've held off on officially declaring support for Java17 until we've received additional feedback but in general I would expect the driver to function fine with Java17.

So far we've only been talking about *running* the driver on Java17.  At the moment the Java driver is built using Java8 bytecode to ensure support with that platform.  The additional ticket referenced above (JAVA-3078) covers building the Java driver with Java17.  There *might* be a move to something like this in future releases.

To be very, very clear however: the driver has been donated to the Apache Software Foundation.  That means any decisions around official support for Java17 and/or building the driver with something other than Java8 bytecode is up to that organization.